# Run app with with other username

Tags: java

I'm using an IBM driver to connect DB2 database. Everything works perfect untill i start it at the PC with cyrillic username. In this case driver throws error: 
`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10402][11146][3.63.123] Cannot convert Unicode string to Ebcdic string. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null`.
The only way i found is to start application from other username that has proper name, but System.setProperty("user.name","user") doesn't work. I can use Duser.name=user, but it only works when i'm starting app with .bat file, but doesn't work if i compile with this key in project properties in NetBeans. 
Can someone help with at least one of this issues?

**upd:** Code i use to connect to the DB2

```
public Connection Connect(String url, Connection con){
   Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"); 
   String User ="energy"; 
   String Pass ="energy"; 
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,User,Pass); 
   return con;
}
```

Login/password are not in cyrillic, only the wundows username is. As i found, it's a bug of DB2 driver, but how can i get round this bug?

Comment: getProperty or setProperty?

Comment: The problem appears to be that the *shudder* EBCDIC encoding of your (presumably legacy) DB2 database can't represent characters in that username. Please post the code where you're setting up the driver; you can usually include a username there.

Comment: @chrylis 
`public Connection Connect(String url, Connection con){
   Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
   String User ="energy";
   String Pass ="energy";
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,User,Pass);
   return con;
}`
I'm noob here so can't set code in comments properly :)

@SašaŠijak setProperty, just a mistype

Comment: @crzbt - it's ok, nobody can put properly formatted code in comments.  You can edit your original question, though. :)

Comment: Can you debug the driver and find out how it's reading that username? Also, I strongly recommend reporting the error to IBM.

Comment: @chrylis they know about it and already fixed it in 10.5 version, but i have to use older one due to license. I've tried to debug, and didn't find anything. May be that i didn't go deet enough...